# Cygwin G++ linker (ld.exe) on Windows 7 cannot find libc.so.6 and other library files

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

I am using g++ in a cygwin terminal to link several c object files and c++ object files together into a single shared executable.  The linker tells me that there are several libraries it cannot find.  However, I can list them, using the locations where the linker states that it is looking for them:

`g++ -g -o myProg.so  *.o  -shared
c:/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../../x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/bin/ld.exe: *cannot find /lib/libc.so.6*
c:/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../../x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/bin/ld.exe: *cannot find /x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/lib/libc_nonshared.a*
c:/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../../x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/bin/ld.exe: *cannot find /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2*
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`


`$ ls   /lib/libc.so.6
/lib/libc.so.6`

`$ ls   /x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/lib/libc_nonshared.a
/x86_64-vityan-linux-gnu/lib/libc_nonshared.a`

`$ ls   /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

I have tried renaming the .so files to .dll with no success.

I have tried to use the g++ switch '--sysroot' ( --sysroot=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/) with no success.

I have tried adding the g++ switch '-B /cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/' with no success.

The thing that's really got me confused is that I did this same thing on a similar project about 6 months ago - no issues.  And, the system clearly shows that the libraries are there.

What is missing that ld.exe needs to find these files?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to cross compile for linux, and you don't have the libraries installed. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Yes - trying to cross compile to run on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit Linux.   I went back to the cygwin install and checked for these libraries and all of the g++ stuff I could find.

Comment: Reinstall of Cygwin resolved the issue.  Details in Answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a quick analysis of what packages I had installed in Cygwin. I had several of the mingw g++ toolchain packages as well (which don't get used), and a bunch of other stuff. I only use Cygwin for a few specific projects, so I reinstalled: removed all of the other g++ toolchain items, and just installed the cygwin gcc 64 bit toolchain packages. Project now compiles without issue. Closing question.

Comment: After finding this same issue on another system, and digging in some more, I believe the root cause is a permissions issue.  I haven't been able to prove it yet, but the symptoms seem to point this way.  Will update with further comments if I figure out what's going on.

Comment: Finally got this - it took three of us looking at what was going on:
There was a copy of one of the source files:
i.e. 
source_file.cpp
source_file_copy.cpp

Since both files had the same methods defined, the linker could not link their corresponding object files. It's beyond me to guess why the linker did not print out a message that might help one determine this.

Eliminating the copy of the file and it's corresponding '.o' file fixed the issue